# Push notification with new device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I register for push notifications when the user logs in or registers.

Then, in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, I save that token ([deviceToken hexRepresentation]) as an NSString in NSUserDefaults, and send the token to my server.

A user has reported this problem: They used to have an iPhone 5C (iOS 7). Now they have a new iPhone 6 (iOS 8), and restored from backup (the restore included the app). Push notifications no longer work, even though they have everything set up OK in Settings > Notifications.

I'm guessing that their real device token has changed, so how do I get the new one? And how do I tell if this has happened?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you checking for the iOS 8 version of registering for notifications? I noticed them breaking on my app yesterday and sure enough the [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:] method doesn't work on iOS 8 so I had to change it to use [application registerUserNotificationSettings:] then [application registerForRemoteNotifications] on iOS 8

Comment: Yes, I'm handling iOS 7 and 8 push notification registration fine. It's just the restored device that is the issue.

Comment: @cannyboy did you find any reliable solution to this problem?